# Imagepath Replace in Document Directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

For using  `NSFileManager`, if exists the Image path  or folder,how to replace new image path (or) Folder in document directory .

Is there the replace feature in `NSFileManager`?
(how to replace image path position with new image path in document directory)

Comment: Use same path which you want to replace and write again your file will get replaced as @metronic said

Answer (score 1):

You want to owerwrite an image, just write it to file.
If an image with the same name exists at the same path, **it will be overwritten**:

```
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;

UIImage * imageToSave = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"];
NSData * binaryImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToSave);

[binaryImageData writeToFile:[basePath  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.png"] atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not replace a path using NSFileManager because, you've already saved ImagePath. Now you can check if that path is exists then you can remove that filePath using this:

```
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:Path] == YES) {
  [fileManager removeItemAtPath:Path error:&error];
}
```

Now save your new path.

If you want to replace content then simple remove first then write again using

```
writeToFile:filePath
```

Comment: No need if removing old file. It's automatically replaced by new image.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* foofile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:foofile];
    NSLog(fileExists ? @"Yes" : @"No");
    if (fileExists == YES)
    {
        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", aDocumentsDirectory,filename];
        NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
        [data1 writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }
```